# Get method classname inside decorator at __init__ in python

Tags: python, django, decorator

I'm trying to somehow 'register' a method inside a class (`@classmethod`) with a decorator to be able to call it later on with ease.

So far I've tried in my decorator to get the whole 'namespace' with no results.

I'm only able to get the `__module__` but I can't get the name of the class where this method resides (because I register it during the `__init__`, not during `__call__` inside my custom decorator).

Is there any way to achieve this?

I think that the only way is to `inspect` the whole file and somehow test if the method exists inside each of the classes, so `inspect` solutions are also accepted

### More Infos

Basically, I'm trying to fork django-dajaxice and modify [this](https://github.com/jorgebastida/django-dajaxice/blob/master/dajaxice/decorators.py) decorator to be able to register full path functions (comprensive with classname) in order to call for example `my.namespace.views.MyView.as_view(...)` from AJAX (I know that it's more complicated, I'm trying to simplify)

Comment: Your question is rather unclear to me.  Could you show some code?  A broader description of the problem you are trying to solve would also be appreciated -- probably there is an easier way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a class decorator to register your methods instead:

```
def register_methods(cls):
    for name, method in cls.__dict__.items():
        # register the methods you are interested in

@register_methods
class Foo(object):
    def x(self):
        pass
```

You could combine this with a method decorator to annotate the methods you are interested in so you can easily identify them.

As an aside you mention [`@classmethod`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#classmethod), which is a built-in decorator that returns a function which takes a class as it's first argument. In this case you probably don't want to use (or emulate) it.

Comment: I like this approach, but still, this will reduce the flexibility of the code, because I would have to manually add the methods each time I create something new. I think that's the only way without inspecting the module isn't it ?